# PHP - Populating a multidimensional array with a sql result, specifying keys to aggregate similar results

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I'm trying to have an array that is gonna be passed as JSON to an angular View.
The structure of the sql result is roughly :

- Order Number
- Supplier
- Qty
- Date
- OrderState
- ProductA(including size)
- GenericA(excluding size)
- LibA
- TypeA(Package,Batch,Product)
- SizeA
- SizeNameA
- ProductB
- GenericB
- LibB
- TypeB
- SizeB
- SizeNameB
- QtyPerSizeB
- ProductC
- GenericC
- LibC
- TypeC
- SizeC
- SizeNameC
- QtyPerSizeC

It is done with left joins, so the cost concerns the last non null product.

If it's a package :

- ProductA -> Package
- ProductB -> Batch (Child of A)
- ProductC -> Product (Child of B)

If it's a batch or a package with no batches :

- ProductA -> Package/Batch
- ProductB -> Product
- ProductC -> *null*

If it's only products :

- ProductA -> Product
- ProductB/C -> *null*

So I need to have a hierarchy of some sort so I can loop through these objects.
Something similar to this :

```
{
  "order": {
    "infos": {},
    "products": {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "Package",
      "sizes": {
        "1": {
          "qty": "",
          "price": ""
        },
        "2": {
          "qty": "",
          "price": ""
        }
      },
      "children": {
        "name": "x",
        "type": "Batch",
        "sizes": {
          "1": {
            "qty": "",
            "price": ""
          },
          "2": {
            "qty": "",
            "price": ""
          }
        },
        "children": {
          "name": "x",
          "type": "Batch",
          "sizes": {
            "1": {
              "qty": "",
              "price": ""
            },
            "2": {
              "qty": "",
              "price": ""
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried setting each of them by looping through all the results but due to the complexity, it takes too long to develop/modify/maintain.

So I was wondering if there was any way to specify another array containing keys and instructions (something like "parent of","sum of","child of"), and then merge the sql result into a multidimensional array that follows the structure above.

I look forward to reading your comments, you geniuses, and thanks for reading !

Raekh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay no responses.
I ended up creating classes that describe the data that I want.
If you're in need of a similar structure, contact me and I'll share how I did it.